# Update a lambda function iteratively in a loop

Tags: python, lambda

I want to update a python lambda function for several times, e.g.,

```
f = lambda x: 0
for t in range(10):
    g_t = .... # some function independent of f
    f = lambda x: f(x) + g_t(x) # update f for 10 times
```

calling f gives me:

```
...

File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>

File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>

...

File "<stdin>", line 3, in <lambda>

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Anyway to get around this?

Comment: What is the actual task you're trying to solve?

Comment: This code alone can't cause stack overflow because you never invoke the function. Please provide all of the code necessary to reproduce the error you're describing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you invoke `f` after the snippet you've pasted, you'll get unbounded recursion, and will eventually exceed the maximum stack depth.

This is because Python closures are captured lexically, meaning they point at the variable name in scope, not the specific value of the variable at the point in time when the lambda is created. When the final value of `f` is invoked, the `f(x)` expression will recursively invoke the final value of `f`, not the value from the previous iteration.

The workaround is to pass the current value of `f` as an argument to the new lambda you are creating, instead of closing over it:

```
f = lambda x: 0
for t in range(10):
    g_t = lambda x: 1 # some function independent of f
    f = lambda x, curr_f=f: curr_f(x) + g_t(x) # pass f as a default argument to the lambda
print(f(0)) # prints 10, no stack overflow
```

Comment: Excellent answer! The line `f = lambda x, f=f: f(x) + g_t(x)` is cryptic yet pythonic!  :P

Comment: @varun Sorry, didn't intend for that to be cryptic. I've simply added an extra argument named `f` to the lambda, and immediately passed the variable `f` as its default value.

Comment: It's pythonic although it is cryptic. I meant that as a compliment! One might have to read through that statement a couple of times before understanding it. That's a clever way of using default parameter as a function  :)